# Complex Measures: Pushforward

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**Problem**

Given Borel spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Consider a complex measure:
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}(X)\to\mathbb{C}$$

Regard a pushforward:
$$h\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y):\quad\nu:=\mu\circ h^{-1}$$

Then one has:
$$|\nu|=|\mu\circ h^{-1}|=|\mu|\circ h^{-1}$$

How can I check this?

**Reference**

This is a note for: [Pushforward (SM)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365246/79762)

Comment: Is the relation for the total measures correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $v \in \mathcal{B}(\Pi)$? Did you mean $v \in L^1(|\nu|)$?

Comment: @LostinaMaze: Ah no, sorry. *(Corrected!)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is correct.

Let us consider $X =\{\pm1\}$ and $Y =\{0\}$ as well as $h \equiv 0$ and $\mu =\delta_1 - \delta_{-1}$.

It is not hard to see $\nu \equiv 0$ and hence $|\nu|\equiv 0$ but $|\mu|=\delta_1 +\delta_{-1}$.

That implies:

$$
|\nu|(Y)=0\neq2=|\mu|(X)=|\mu|(h^{-1}(Y)).
$$

Comment: Nice :D That was exactly I was looking for. Thanks!!!