# Spectral Measures: Pushforward

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This thread is Q&A.*

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}(N)\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

And its spectral measure:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad N=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$$

Regard pushforward:
$$E_\eta:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad E_\eta(A):=E(\eta^{-1}A)$$

> Then one obtains:
>   $$\eta(N)=\int\lambda\,\mathrm{d}E_\eta(\lambda)$$
>
> And for compositions:
>   $$\vartheta(\eta(N))=(\vartheta\circ\eta)(N)$$

How can I prove this?

**Application**

For invertibles one gets:
$$\mathcal{N}\eta(N)=(0):\quad\eta(N)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\eta}(N)=\frac{1}{\eta(N)}$$

That justifies notation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the pushforward:
$$E_\eta:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad E_\eta(A):=E(\eta^{-1}A)$$

Their domain agree as:*
$$\int|\vartheta\circ\eta|^2\mathrm{d}\nu_\varphi(\lambda)=\int|\vartheta|^2\mathrm{d}\nu^\eta_\varphi$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$\mathcal{D}:=\mathcal{D}(\vartheta\circ\eta)(N)=\mathcal{D}(\vartheta\circ\eta)(E)=\mathcal{D}\vartheta(E_\eta)$$

In particular one has:**
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{D}:\quad\int|\vartheta\circ\eta|\,\mathrm{d}|\mu_{\varphi\chi}|<\infty\quad\int|\vartheta|\,\mathrm{d}|\mu^\eta_{\varphi\chi}|<\infty$$

For simple functions:
$$\int s\circ\eta\,\mathrm{d}\mu_{\varphi\chi}=\sum_kb_k\mu(\eta^{-1}B_k)=\int s\,\mathrm{d}\mu^\eta_{\varphi\chi}$$

By Lebesgue one gets:***
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{D}:\quad\int\vartheta\circ\eta\,\mathrm{d}\mu_{\varphi\chi}=\int\vartheta\,\mathrm{d}\mu^\eta_{\varphi\chi}(\lambda)$$

But note that it was:
$$\mathrm{id}(E_\eta)=\eta(E)=\eta(N)$$

Concluding the assertion.

**See the thread: [Pushforward (BM)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365177/79762)*

***Note the thread: [Pushforward (CM)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1332227/79762)*

****See the thread: [Lebesgue (CM)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365258/79762)*