# Complex Measures: Lebesgue

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given a Borel space $\Omega$.

Consider a complex measure:
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{C}$$

Regard a sequence:
$$\eta_n\in\mathcal{L}(\Omega):\quad\eta_n\to\eta$$

Suppose one finds:
$$\overline{\eta}\in\mathcal{L}(\mu):\quad|\eta_n|\leq|\overline{\eta}|$$

> Then it follows:
>   $$\int\eta\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\lim_n\int\eta_n\mathrm{d}\mu$$

How can I check this?

**Reference**

This is a lemma for [Pushforward (SM)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365246/79762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the density it is:
$$|\eta_n|\cdot|u|=|\eta_n|\cdot1\leq|\overline{\eta}|$$

So one obtains:
$$\lim_n\int\eta_n\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\lim_n\int\eta_n\cdot u\mathrm{d}|\mu|=\int\eta\cdot u\mathrm{d}|\mu|=\int\eta\,\mathrm{d}\mu$$

Concluding the assertion.